# How can I insert previous Commit ID ( or something similar ) into my source using GitHub

Tags: git, github, pre-commit

My example repository is [this one](https://github.com/dvdvideo1234/Test) with its last commit [(K + 1)](https://github.com/dvdvideo1234/Test/commit/5ce004eea0b6c1ee26073e998e89f8cec3117111) and I want to automatically insert the previous one's [( K )](https://github.com/dvdvideo1234/Test/commit/c2928d9091e0743cb22b38d962c75f97791767a0) commit ID ( The hash at the end of the URL) inside a source file in the repo when I commit (K + 1) ( Let's say [test.c](https://github.com/dvdvideo1234/Test/blob/master/test.c) ). How can I make it, so this commit ID gets inserted in to the source like a string. So far I Google-ed and found the following strings:

```
$Id:$
$Id$
```

But so far nether of those can make it ( c2928d9091e0743cb22b38d962c75f97791767a0 ) appear inside test.c

That way I can make the particular system print this hash, to identify on which machine which version do I have.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442874/in-git-how-can-i-write-the-current-commit-hash-to-a-file-in-the-same-commit).

Comment: This one is for Linux, and I guess I should run those commands somehow "git rev-parse HEAD > filename"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I populate the Git commit ID into a file when I commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524225/how-can-i-populate-the-git-commit-id-into-a-file-when-i-commit)

Comment: How can I make those Git attributes. In the ".git" there is no such ting, but when I try to create a file with that name i get "You must specify a file name" because it has only extension....

Comment: I tried with the last commit https://github.com/dvdvideo1234/Test

Managed to add ".gitattributes" with "test.c ident" inside it and "Git Commit ID: $Id$" inside "test.c"