# Updating project version number on git push

Tags: git, version, push, increment

I have a project hosted on Github, and I would like to set it up such that the project has a version number, and the version number is only updated when the master branch is updated, either directly by a push, or via a merged Pull Request.

Is there any way to let git/Bitbucket update a specific number in a specific file? It is OK if there is just a dedicated file for this purpose, containing a single number. I assume I will be able to write code that upon asking what version my project is using, will simply read that file. My project is a C# Web API project, although I'm not sure that matters much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any way to let git/Bitbucket update a specific number in a specific file?

Not a file tracked in the repo, since it would be part of *another* commit.
As explained in "[How do I enable ident string for Git repos?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1796675/6309)", that is a task (generating build info) better left to a build system, rather than [some kind of hook/content filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3442988/6309).

Any repo hosting services can have webhooks ([GitHub](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/), [BitBucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Manage+Bitbucket+hooks)) allowing you to attach some kind of process to an event (like a git push), but those process would be executed on the client side (a client listening to the [JSON payload](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#payloads) generated by said webhook): nothing is executed on GitHub/BitBucket servers (except maybe [BitBucket brokers](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Manage+Bitbucket+hooks#ManageBitbuckethooks-Writingyourownbrokers), mainly to communicate with other third-party services).

One way which *could* work though is a post-commit hook (executed on the client, before pushing) using:

- [`git notes` as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16135886/6309)
- [`git describe` as in this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11660153/6309)

That way, each commit would update a [`git notes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes) on said commit, with the content of a [`git describe`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe).

The idea with git notes is they don't change the SHA1 associated to the repo, meaning you can add those *after* a commit.
You can then [push those notes to GitHub and see them](https://github.com/blog/707-git-notes-display).

```
git push origin refs/notes/*
```

See more with "[Git Notes and GitHub](https://speakerdeck.com/matthewmccullough/git-notes-and-github) " by [Matthew McCullough](https://github.com/matthewmccullough).

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I'm using Jenkins, so I will investigate if there exists a job that can take care of this.