# Symfony versioning of a site based on GIT version

Tags: git, symfony, gitlab

OK, a question that seems to be harder (for me) then it appears at first.
I develop sites with the symphony framework.
But some of the sites are put on servers to which I have no direct access.
So, in order to keep track if the latest version is put, I have added a value in the HTML header of the login page.
Now I always manually update this value (in the TWIG).
And now the question I'm struggling with:

Is it possible to "automate" that the latest value of the GIT commit is added automatically (and transparently, so meaning no effort is required)?
I've been thinking of adding a value to the .env file and trying to get this populated with the correct value, but to be honest I'm a bit struggling to see how I can make this work....

If there are other suggestions to keep a decent version tracking which is relatively transparent for the actual users of the site, then that is of course also welcome...

Comment: Do you use GitHub Actions for pushing updates to these servers? If so you could automate the value via that, if not then manually will be the only way, afaik.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I just use it for the version history and the changes. 

I compile the "symfony" packages and then send them to the user-representative that extract these to a server with no internet connectivity (it's a company internal solution)...

Comment: The only other way i can think of is to create a script that runs when you commit and increment a counter. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442874/in-git-how-can-i-write-the-current-commit-hash-to-a-file-in-the-same-commit) might help and give you some ideas to add the version. Basically, on commit it could update a file in your project and then your twig template can always just read this file..

Comment: Do you mean the Symfony version? Or the Git commit hash? The Symfony version is available as `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel::VERSION` but your own Kernel extends that so you can use `App\Kernel::VERSION`

Comment: The symfony version is rather static, so I mean either the GIT commit hash or the date I create the build or... 
Well anything that allows my to see weather or not the latest version was put, preferably without me having to do extra steps since I consistently forget to update the "manual" timestamp which is in it now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think about and select from at least 2 strategies

### Clean and smudge filters

In-file replacement, as it (done|expect to be) now

As explained in [Keyword Expansion](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_keyword_expansion) chapter in GitBook

> In the .gitattributes file, you can set a filter for particular paths and then set up scripts that will process files just before they’re checked out and just before they’re staged

I.e have some "magic-string" expanding into *anything you want to have* in WorkTree and collapsed into original form before placing back into repo, thus - don't appear as content-changes in git's history

Also, for *anything you want to have*, output of [`git describe`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) (or any other inique-id generator) may be good candidate, you have to have only at least one tag in repo

### Export-subst

External file, appearing on `git archive` operation in an archive-target *automagically* with any custom content inside. Can be included into any twig-template or page

No script-coding for smudge|clean filters, only file(s) [with git log’s formatting and keyword-expansion processing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_export_subst)

Comment: I will look into the Export-subst solution further. According to what I've read this will indeed do the job. Thank you, Lazy Badger !