# How to read latest commit hash programmatically?

Tags: node.js, git, version

I want to print the latest commit hash in my Node.js application.

I found a similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3442874/14051057), but it's not what I have in mind. I want to read this information from within Node.js, without running `git` commands in a terminal.

So if possible, I want to read the `.git` folder with `fs`, find the latest commit hash and write it to a variable. This file looks relevant: `.git/logs/refs/heads/master`.

Can I simply read the last non-empty line of this file and parse the commit hash from there? Any pitfalls I should look for? Any better ways? It's safe to assume I have only one branch (master)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you want the currently checked out commit or the latest commit of a specific branch (such as master)? Because the path you mention does the later. In other words: do you want `git rev-parse HEAD` or `git rev-parse master`?

Comment: Don't know really, not that proficient with git. But I want to do it from within Node.js, not a terminal.

Answer (score 2):

To get the hash for the current (pointed to by the `HEAD`) commit:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

To get the hash for the last commit on `master` branch (in case you moved `HEAD` to a different commit using `git checkout` or `git switch`):

```
git rev-parse master
```

Comment: If I read OP correctly they want to do it without a `git` command call.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Using `git` commands is the only correct way. Reading files in `.git/` subdirectory is like reading binary SQL dumps instead of using a proper client and SQL commands. Unnecessary and fragile (the structure is private, it belongs to Git and is subject to change at any moment).

Comment: Yes but I want my node application to read the commit and print it inside an HTML file or something. Maybe a node library for that?

Comment: @wololoo That information should be in the question and in the tags.

Comment: I wanted to keep it not specific to Node so maybe people from other platforms can use the information. But you are right, I emphasized this more specifically in the question now.

Comment: @phd I agree and want to emphasize that using `git` directly (or using a library as libgit2) is the only reliable approach. For instance the assumption "I want to read the .git folder" fails spectacularly for [worktrees](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) where `.git` is a file instead.